# How to run HIVE and IMPALA shell commands using python?

Tags: python, hive, subprocess, impala

I have to run HIVE queries using python script eg,
For this `$ bdscc -e "show databases"`
I want to do the same in python, but I am getting error-

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['bdscc', '-e', 'show databases'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to do this in python?

PS- The command `$ bdscc -e "show databases"` from terminal is running fine.

UPDATE--  `bdscc` is an alias set by my company for HIVE shell

Comment: **1.** What is `bdscc`? Even Google has no clue... **2.** Why don't you just use `impyla` (from Cloudera) which is a _"Python client for HiveServer2 implementations (e.g., Impala, Hive) "_ >> https://github.com/cloudera/impyla

Comment: **1.** `bdscc` is an alias set by company (Sorry I didn't knew this). So, basically it is a way to run HIVE queries without actually starting HIVE shell. **2.** I didn't knew I can also connect to HIVE using `impyla`, I just did that and its working fine. Thanks @SamsonScharfrichter

Comment: Fine, so please update your question and explain how you solved the issue (i.e. with a workaround)

Comment: I imported `impyla`, connected to hive using `connect(host = 'host_name', port = 10000, auth_mechanism='GSSAPI', kerberos_service_name= 'hive')`. Then I got connected to hive, made a cursur object and started running queries. (It seems inside python, it is not recognising the alias `bdscc` for HIVE).